# jquery barrating is not working during i need multiple star

Tags: jquery, jquery-bar-rating

"here is my code, i need multiple barrating in loop is running by VueJS normally, but rating is not showing, i am calling barrating from other file like below:"

```
$( '#example-fontawesome' ).barrating({
   theme: 'fontawesome-stars',
   showSelectedRating: false,
   onSelect: function(){
       ratingviewmodel.ratingSubmit();
   }
});

$( '.examplefontawesome' ).barrating({
    theme: 'fontawesome-stars',
    showSelectedRating: false
});
```

### "here id example-fontawesome is working but loop class examplefontawesome is not working"

`<li class="comment thread-even depth-1" v-for="rt in ratingData">
    <div class="comment-author vcard">
        <b class="fn">{{ rt.display_name }}</b>
        <div class="stars stars-example-fontawesome">
            <select class="examplefontawesome" name="rating{{ $index }}">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="br-current-rating"></div>
        <div class="ctime">{{ rt.rating }}</div>
    </div>
</li>`

output:[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use barrating as a directive of vue.js. Just call the instance of barrating under bind method in deirective and set the value using direcetive update method. And directive call as like

`<select class="examplefontawesome" v-barrating name="rating{{ $index }}">`

where v-barrating is a directive.